# How do I do a character compare on text box data in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, tkinter

I have looked all over and can't find what I'm looking for. I have recently started learning python but am now stuck on my one project.

I have a text box called `self.script_txt1` and I'm trying to write a function that will compare every row in that text box with each other to find the odd character.

I know I will need to use a for loop to do this but I can't figure out how to create the loop so that it will run through each char per line then move on to the next row.

For Example, the data inside `self.script_txt1`

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

111111111111111111111111111111111a111111111

1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

11111111a1111111111111111111111111111111111 

1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 

1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 

1111911111111111111111a11111111111111111111 

111111111111111111Z111111111111111111111111 

1111*111*111111111*111*1111111111*111111111 # <-- new inserted line
```

I would like to find all the characters that are different and insert a new line at the bottom with a `*` or `%` to mark the position where the different char was found.

Comment: I don't see your code. And I don't see `tkinter` in code.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: get all text from textbox, split it into lines (`split('\n')`) and use `for` loop to get line-by-line and second `for` loop to get char-by-char from line. And compare char with your list. So all problem has nothing to do with tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read comments in code

```
text = '''1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111a111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111a1111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111911111111111111111a11111111111111111111
111111111111111111Z111111111111111111111111'''

# split text into lines
lines = text.split('\n')

# find length of the longest line
length = max(len(line) for line in lines)
print('length:', length)

# create new line with `1`s (or rather create list with `1`s)
result = ['1']*length
print(' start:', ''.join(result))

# search for chars in lines

# get line-by-line
for line in lines:
    # get char-by-char in line (and enumerate it)
    for idx, char in enumerate(line):
        # check char
        if char != '1': # if char not in ('1', 'x', 'y'):
            # put `*` in correct place in new line
            result[idx] = '*'
            #print('found:', idx, char)

# display new line
new_line = ''.join(result)
print('result:', new_line)
```

Result:

```
length: 43
 start: 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
result: 1111*111*111111111*111*1111111111*111111111
```

Now you have to only get text from textbox and add new line at the end.

Comment: Sorry furas, this is my first time using stackoverflow, was not sure if I had to post my code so far. So here it is.

Comment: Won't allow me to post, too long. Will have a look at the Example you provided. And thank you, appreciate your input.